# redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com in nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have SSL issued for domain.com. Now these url works fine:

```
http://www.example.com -> https://example.com
http://example.com -> https://example.com
https://example.com
```

But when accessed with https://www.example.com it shows the Security Certificate error as:

```
There is a problem with this website’s security certificate.
```

My nginx config (site-available/example.com) is as follows:

```
server {
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return       301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.key;
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

How can I redirect the url https://www.example.com to https://example.com in this config file

Comment: Is the certificate valid for both www.example.com and example.com?

Comment: it is issued for example.com

Comment: That is why you get an error message when you are using it for another domain.

Answer (score 0):

Create a permanent redirect:

```
server {
      charset utf-8;
      listen 80;
      listen 443 ssl;
      server_name www.example.com;

      rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
      charset utf-8;
      listen 80;
      listen 443 ssl;
      server_name example.com;

      location / {
      # this serves the actual content ...
      }

     if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
       rewrite ^/(.*) https://$server_name/$1 permanent;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I edited my config as following:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  example.com *.example.com;
    return       301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;

<-your_other_site_configurations->
...
...
```

Now it is working perfectly! Hope it helped others too!!